# How can I get the x:Name attribute of a ResourceDictionary in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, .net-4.8

As the title says, I just want to get the `x:Name` attribute of a `ResourceDictionary` in code behind.

My `ResourceDictionary`:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary x:Name="DefaultLight"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

My App.Xaml

```xml
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyLib;component/Resources/OutgoingResources.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyLib;component/Resources/Themes/DefaultDark.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

My code behind:

```c#
Console.WriteLine(Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[1].???);
```

Comment: I am making a theme manager and I need to get theme's (`ResourceDictionary`) `x:Name` so I can check which theme is applied etc...

Comment: Maybe that was something you should have mentioned when you posted the question? Anyhow, I added some ideas to my post.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to get the name back out once it's merged.

You can, however, find the source of a resource dictionary:

```
        var mergedDict = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;
        foreach (var rd in mergedDict)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(rd.Source.OriginalString);
        }
```

For:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary  Source="/Resources/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary  Source="/Resources/Dictionary2.xaml"/>
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I get

```
/Resources/Dictionary1.xaml
/Resources/Dictionary2.xaml
```

Rather than Dictionary1 or 2 you can of course name those files DefaultLight.xaml, DefaultDark.xaml etc.

If your purpose is just to see which theme resource dictionary is merged then you could "just" have a key in each of them which tells you.

```
 <clr:String x:Key="CurrentTheme">DefaultDark</clr:String>
```

And of course DefaultLight in the light resource dictionary, with the same key.

If you wanted to have some sort of friendly name for a bunch of resource dictionaries.  You could define a list allows you to decouple.
A class with name, url and IsLoaded bool in a list.  Load whichever you choose in code and mark it as loaded.

Comment: Yes I already know that!!! :) I just wanted to know if I can take the `x:Name` of a `ResourceDictionary`.

Comment: If it wasn't merged?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Name` property of  a `ResourceDictionary` that is set by the XAML processor.

You could create a custom type though that adds a `Name` property though:

```
public class NamedResourceDictionary : ResourceDictionary 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then set the property in the XAML markup:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <local:NamedResourceDictionary Name="Dark" Source="/MyLib;component/Resources/Themes/DefaultDark.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

...and retrieve it by casting the merged resource dictionary to your custom type:

```
var name = (Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0] as NamedResourceDictionary)?.Name;
```